# Ant - Using external file to use in patternset

Tags: maven, ant

In Ant, we use patternset to include or exclude some set of file using a pattern such as

```
<unzip src="${tomcat_src}/tools-src.zip"
       dest="${tools.home}">
    <patternset>
        <include name="**/*.java"/>
        <exclude name="**/Test*.java"/>
    </patternset>
</unzip>
```

Is Ant capable of taking this patternset from an external file say txt or xml?
Seeing around the Ant the wiki does not mention of such usuage, but i am thinking otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using `includesfile/excludesfile` or `includes/excludes` attributes of [`patternset`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/patternset.html).

In case of `includes/excludes`, you can use values of properties stored in your normal property file.